# Swap div's position at certain index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap a div's position from top on and when I click another div then top div can be swap.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="wrap top">
    <input type="text" value="div1" class="textbox " />
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="div2" class="textbox " />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="div3" class="textbox " />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var objectDivs = $('.wrap');
objectDivs.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    objectDivs.eq(0).html($this);
    $this.remove();
})
```

The fact is I don't want to remove the div which I click instead want to swap the positions around.

How Can I do this using jQuery itself?

Comment: If I am not wrong, `objectDivs` is already a jQuery object. `$(objectDivs)` may not be necessary and also will yield the intended results.

Comment: Yes it is jquery object That I made earlier. It is not yeilding results

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".wrap").on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```css
.wrap{background:#eee;padding:10px; margin:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">1</div>
  <div class="wrap">2</div>
  <div class="wrap">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use insertBefore and insertAfter for this.
For example: -

```js
(function($) {
  $(".wrap").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).index() == 0) {
      $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
    } else {
      $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrap1 {
  background: red;
}

.wrap2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap wrap1"></div>
  <div class="wrap wrap2"></div>
</div>
```